# Рефакторинг крупного django проекта

Tags: django, архитектура

Есть большой проект, написанный на django. Условно состоит из двух частей. Основной модуль - что-то вроде CRM и небольшой модуль, рисующий лендинги, используя данные из основного модуля. Обе части доступны с разных доменов.

Что нужно получить:

1. Выделить модуль лендингов в отдельный проект.
2. При этом он должен работать с той же БД что и CRM.
3. Описания общих моделей должны быть в одном месте. Например
   декларации моделей оставить в CRM проекте, а в проект с лэндингами
   импортировать, чтобы не дублировать код и не следить вручную за
   соответствием деклараций в разных проектах.
4. Проекты должны минимально зависеть друг от друга. Любой можно временно
   остановить, не нарушая работу другого.

Comment: А в чём суть вопроса?

Comment: @nomnoms12
Как организовать код, git репозиторий, структура каталогов и т.п. Может есть толковый гайд, или ссылка на репозиторий, где решена подобная задача

Comment: Определитесь, чего именно вы хотите - выделить модуль в отдельный проект, или импортировать модели между модулями. В поставленной форме задача разрешима, но крайне шаманскими методами. Я бы на вашем месте реализовал CRM-часть в качестве API-ориентированного модуля, реализующего операции с данными, и осуществлял передачу данных между ним и лендинг-билдером в виде JSON. В этом случае вы получаете два независимых сервиса, которые могут располагаться на разных серверах и могут быть реализованы независимо друг от друга на чем угодно.

Comment: @cauf написал. Если не сложно, подробнее про то, как можно "расшарить" описание моделей между проектами?

Comment: Используйте git submodules.

Comment: @Дмитрий это не тот путь, который вам нужен. Он чреват большим количеством костылей и далеко не факт, что результат будет адекватно работать